# Return an array from a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, xcode, portability

I'm in the process of learning cpp. I wrote a program today in my normal mode of compiling via g++ on the command line of a mac. I've been double checking my work in XCode as well and found a line of code that is causing the code to not compile in the IDE

the line is:

```
string result[2] = subject[rand() % nsubject];
```

where subject is a multidimensional array of strings wherein each member of the it is an array of two strings and nsubject is an int holding the length of the array. Xcode is saying that: **Array initializer must be an initializer list**, but as stated prior, g++ compiles without nary a complaint. So, being new to the language I assume that this statement is probably poor form. There must be some way of doing this that XCode will find acceptable, yes?

Here is a fragment that may demonstrate the problem, removed from context doesn't make much sense, but the following compiles fine on my terminal fine but fails to build in xcode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string subject[][2] = {
        {"a", "b"},
        {"c", "d"},
        {"e", "f"},
        {"g", "h"},
        {"i", "j"}
    };

    int nsubject = sizeof subject / sizeof subject[0];
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));
    string result[2] = subject[rand() % nsubject];
    cout << result[0] << endl; //should return 'a','c','e','g' or 'i'
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't have many capabilities. Use `std::array` for the semantics you'd expect.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example demonstrating your problem. It's hard to tell what it is with a single line out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, ok. So the problem is that you are trying to declare another array of two strings on this line and assign another array into it:

```
string result[2] = subject[rand() % nsubject];
```

This is not really legit for plain arrays. It should be a pointer with or without a size specified. For example:

```
string *result = subject[rand() % nsubject];
```

... or:

```
string (&result)[2] = subject[rand() % nsubject];
```

Not sure why gcc compiles it though. Hope it helps!

Comment: Very helpful, pointers are still kind of mysterious to me (off to read the chapter in Kernighan and Ritchie, again)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to assign one of sub-arrays in `subject` to a new array.  Xcode probably doesn't like this because you don't typically assign entire arrays to other arrays.  g++ is handling it fine because it realizes that both variables are of type `string*`.  If you explicitly tell Xcode that you are assigning a pointer to a pointer variable, you should be fine.  The following should compile anywhere.

```
string* result = subject[rand() % nsubject];
```

Just be aware that `result` does not contain a copy of the contents of the sub-array in `subject`, it is only a reference to the array.